# Set value in TextBox field

Tags: android

I want to set in countersunk the size of contact_array_from_db. I tried the code below, but it is not working.

```
TextView countershv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.shv);
ArrayList<Hearing> contact_array_from_db = db.Get_HearingCaseall(curDate);

for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

    int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
    String clientid = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getClientId();
    String courtid = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getCourtTypeId();
    String dateofhearing = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getDateofHearing();
    String remarks = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getHearingRemarks();
    String dateofnexthearing = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getDateofnexthearing();
    String nexthearingremarks = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getNexthearingremarks();
    String againstremarks = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getAgainstremarks();
    String casereferences = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getCasereferences();

    Hearing cnt = new Hearing();
    cnt.setID(tidno);
    cnt.setclient_id(clientid);
    cnt.setCourtTypeId(courtid);
    cnt.setDateofHearing(dateofhearing);
    cnt.setHearingRemarks(remarks);
    cnt.setDateofnexthearing(dateofnexthearing);
    cnt.setNexthearingremarks(nexthearingremarks);
    cnt.setAgainstremarks(againstremarks);
    cnt.setCasereferences(casereferences);

    contact_data.add(cnt);
}
int counterhanu = contact_array_from_db.size();


/*contact_data.contains(counter);*/
db.close();
cAdapter = new Contact_Adapter(Main_Screen_Hearingfull.this, R.layout.listview_hearingfull,
    contact_data,counterhanu);
Contact_listview.setAdapter(cAdapter);
cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
countershv .setText(counterhanu);
}
```

We get the value in counterhanu, but I want to set this value in countershv. I am not sure how? I tried this `countershv.setText(counterhanu);` but it is not working.

Comment: When asking questions, you need to provide more than it doesn't work. You need to provide stacktraces, exact error messages. That said, I think @Aashir is correct. The int you are sending to setText will result in it searching for a resource by that ID, instead of setting text.

Comment: Please try and use full words, not text message abbreviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
countershv.setText(""+counterhanu);
```

Instead of:

```
countershv.setText(counterhanu);
```

Comment: its working...thanx...can u say dat how to pass dis value of countershv on main activity when click on main activity page den go in dis page....now i want to get dis value onload to mainactivity..hw to proceed??

Comment: can u say dat how to pass dis value of countershv on main activity when click on main activity page den go in dis page....now i want to get dis value onload to mainactivity..hw to proceed??

Comment: Hi sorry, I missed the notification. You can use I intents to pass them along activities when starting them or otherwise. Use intent.putExtra(value) to send it and intent.getExtra(value) to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can explain a little bit more, or reduce your own problem. I see a lot of code and is that all relevant to the problem? I see you are using a database connection, is that connection working? Do you know network connections are not instant.

You cannot .setText(Integer i) you have to use .setText(String str) or something. So you use one of these three:

```
textView.setText(intergerValue + ""); 
textView.setText("" + intergerValue);
textView.setText(Interger.toString(intergerValue));

textView.setText(R.string.value); // this is a static string value in /res/values/strings.xml
```

So next time when you are debugging try to the same with less code. I mean you want to set an integer that you retrevied from a database-connection. But if you had tested that an int you had set yourself wouldnt work too, you might have seen the bug yourself or you could have asked here a short question.

Comment: its working...thanx...can u say dat how to pass dis value of countershv on main activity when click on main activity page den go in dis page....now i want to get dis value onload to mainactivity..hw to proceed??